# React header component with slots

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React app which has some nested react router switches and non trivial logic involving changing header content based on the currently displayed page.

I have previously seen two solutions for this problem:

1. A `<Header/>` that knows absolutely everything about every single possible route and the state of the app
2. Flat page layout: every page renders its own instance of `<Header />`

Both solutions suck donkey balls in my opinion. I think that the header must be fed shit and kept in the dark. All it has to do is to stay at the top of the page. Inspired by React Helmet I want to make a declarative solution to this problem.

Let's suppose that we have a header with three sections: left, right and center. At the root of our application we render something like

```
return (
    <HeaderLeft>
        <Logo />
    </HeaderLeft>
    ...
)
```

Which as expected display a logo.

Somewhere deeper in the hierarchy of the component tree we have a `NestedPage` that needs to change what is displayed in the left section of the header. So we simple do

```
return (
    <HeaderLeft>
        <SomethingElse />
    </HeaderLeft>
    ...
)
```

The trick is when we navigate away from the `NestedPage` we need to put back in the `<HeaderLeft/>` that which was there before we came to the `NestedPage`.

I came up with a somewhat +/- working solution involving react context and stack:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-mendeleev-0b5y4?file=/src/MainPage.js

But this things relies heavily on the useEffects execution order.

**The Question**

Does anyone have an idiomatic solution/idea of a pattern/link to how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: will [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-water-nf8j9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) work for you?

Comment: @Yousaf without going into details, no. Your solution is the contrary of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having gone through React Helmet source code I ended up using [this little jewel](https://github.com/gaearon/react-side-effect)

It does exactly what I need: collects synchronously props from all instances in the render order.

Thus we can get the last `children` rendered:

```js
function reducePropsToState(props) {
  return props[props.length - 1];
}
```

The tricky part was to let the `Header` component know what to render. Fortunately we are all software engineers and React runs on javascript.

I created a simple observable singleton:

```js
class Observable {
  constructor() {
    this.value = null;
    this.subscribers = [];
    this.raf = null;
    this.notify = this.notify.bind(this);
  }

  subscribe(s) {
    this.subscribers.push(s);
    s(this.value);
  }

  setValue(c) {
    this.value = c || null;
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.raf);
    this.raf = requestAnimationFrame(this.notify);
  }

  notify() {
    this.subscribers.forEach((subscriber) => {
      subscriber(this.value);
    });
  }
}
```

In the header component we subscribe to this observable and update local state:

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    contentObservable.subscribe((v) => {
      setContent(v);
    });
  }, []);
```

[Demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-leaf-kucq4?file=/src/Header.js:741-892)